# How to debug a task configuration instead of running one on JetBrains IDE startup

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to force JetBrains IDE startup tasks to be **debugged** instead of being **run**?

Specifically, I want to configure WebStorm **Settings | Tools | Startup Tasks** to automatically perform a JavaScript debug task on IDE startup. The debug task only works by **debugging** it instead of **running** it, but it seems that WebStorm performs startup tasks by simply **running** it. I'm using WebStorm 2022.3.

I'm expecting the task to be performed on startup as if it is executed by clicking the Debug button on the top right of the IDE.

[image]

Comment: You cannot do that. Simply because this functionality was not made to be used this way. If you need such a functionality -- file a feature Request ticket at WebStorm Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB (post a link to a ticket back here so we can follow it)

Answer (score 1):

debug mode for startup tasks is not supported right now. However, we have a corresponding [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203872/Define-Startup-Tasks-that-run-in-Debug-mode) on our bug tracker. We would appreciate it if you could upvote the issue to demonstrate additional interest and bring increased awareness to the issue.